# How to find a word inside a PDF from PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I would like to locate in which page(s) a word is located inside a pdf programatically. My application runs on php over linux.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad, show us what you have tried, and what you are having issues with.

Answer (score 1):

Is it readable with a text editor?
If it is, you can loop the content and find the string with a regular expression. If the string Is variable and you are the one who wrote the file, try to put some fixed string before.
In some cases under Linux we use pdftops to convert the PDF in a human readable format, find the string looping the content file, and back to PDF with pstopdf.